# Получение списка всех таксономий wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть задача нужно в селект выгружать список всех созданных в вордпрессе рубрик, перерыл кучу функций в WP, но все они завязаны на том что бы брать рубрики у текущего поста. Мб кто-то подскажет как можно взять обьект всех таксономий созданных в wordpress что бы в дальнейшем вытянуть с него нужные мне данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть функция `get_taxonomies`:

```
$args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
);
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, 'objects' );
```

Подробнее: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_taxonomies